# Kubernetes cluster role with permissions to watch events

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to create a cluster role with permissions to watch events, but it seems that I'm missing something.

I'm using the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: watch-events
  namespace: test
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: watch-events-cluster
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: watch-events-cluster
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: watch-events-cluster
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: watch-events
  namespace: test
```

No mater what I try with `kubectl auth can-i watch events --as watch-events` I always get a **no**.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RBAC is correct and will give cluster wide permission to watch events across all namespaces but the kubectl command is incorrect.The command should be

```
kubectl auth can-i watch events --as=system:serviceaccount:test:watch-events
```

Comment: hello @arghya, this also doesn't work, and according to k8s documentation: ClusterRoleBinding may be used to grant permission at the cluster level and in all namespaces.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding

So I shouldn't be limited to -n test in this case.

Comment: So you still get no..I tried the same command and same rbac and I got yes. I tried removing -n as well and still got yes which is expected. Yes you are right cluster role gives cluster wide permission

Comment: You are right @Arghya... Worked now...
I couldn't find in the k8s documentation why I have to use ```system:serviceaccount:test:``` though.

Comment: this looks a fake command, if you run with `--as=system:serviceaccount:test:watch-even`, event the account is not exist, you still get `yes` and this command doen't report the problem.

Comment: its for impersonating a user or service account. I am aware that it does not report problem properly but this is AFAIK a handy command to test permission of a user or service account..Do you have a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you are making api calls against the swagger api for Kubernetes, you need to specify the Events api group properly with the suffix `.k8s.io`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#-strong-api-groups-strong-

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: my-custom-role
  namespace: default
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
      - events.k8s.io
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - '*'
---
```

Answer (score -1):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions

> Default RBAC policies grant scoped permissions to control-plane components, nodes, and controllers, **but grant no permissions to service accounts outside the kube-system namespace** (beyond discovery permissions given to all authenticated users).

Comment: Op has defined a cluster role and grant though?